# using jquery to change list items is changing all list items, when i want to only change one list item

Tags: jquery

so i'm basically changing the class on a span within a list item
here's some context:

```
 <li>
    <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
    <div class="shopping-item-controls">
      <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
```

I want to change it to

```
 <span class="shopping-item__checked"> ...
```

The code I have now changes all of the list items. How can I target only the ones that are associated with the button under it?

For a while it was tough for me to target the 
    
So I have an odd way of doing that by using `.parent().children('span')`
I've tried using `"this"` instead of `"div.shopping-item-controls"`)

```
  $('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', event => {
    $('div.shopping-item-controls').parent().children('span').attr('class', 'shopping-item__checked');
  })
```

There are no error messages, but upon clicking the button, all of the shopping list items get crossed off instead of just the one.

Comment: `$('div.shopping-item-controls')` selects all the `div`s which have that class, so the subsquent operation will affect all of the parents' child `span`s. You should go back to using `this` to isolate the elements relating to the button that was clicked.

Comment: when i do ` $(this).attr('class', 'shopping-item__checked');` nothing happens
is there a way to access the span class from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
 $('.shopping-item-toggle').on('click', function(){

    $( this ).parent().siblings('span').addClass('shopping-item__checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should select the div above the button:

```
$(this).prev('div.shopping-item-controls').attr('class', 'shopping-item__checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it so:

```js
const $shoppingItemToggle = $('.shopping-item-toggle')

$shoppingItemToggle.on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li').find('span').attr('class', 'shopping-item__checked');
})
```

```css
.shopping-item {
  color: yellow
}
.shopping-item__checked {
  color: cyan
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
  <div class="shopping-item-controls">
    <button class="shopping-item-toggle">shopping-item-toggle</button>
  </div>
</li>
```